# Error: Argument of � has an extra }. marked in /newpage

Tags: errors, debugging

I was given with the following template in LaTex and I got directly the error 'Argument of � has an extra }.' in line 43 (where the first /newpage is).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[bottom,hang]{footmisc} 
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{array,              %better tables
            tabularx,           %instead of tabular*             
            booktabs,           %tables for good publications
}
\usepackage{afterpage,hyperref} 
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    numbers=left,
    xleftmargin=15pt,
}


%--------------------------MAKETITLE-------------------------------%
\title{title}
\date{\today}
\author{ME} 

\begin{document}

%--------------------------BEGINNING-------------------------------%
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{roman} 
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage %here is marked the error
\tableofcontents
\newpage
```

Comment: Try if it works if you remove the ucs and the inputenc package.

Comment: don't use `\usepackage{ucs}\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` with current latex.

Comment: thanks that worked!